# Why capacitance is constant?

Tags: electrostatics, voltage, capacitance

I am new to the field of electrodynamics and I recently came across the definition of capacitance as
$$C = \frac{Q}{V}$$

It is said that capacitance is constant, which implies that total charge of the one conductor is proportional to the voltage difference between the two conductors. But we know that
$$Q = \int ρ(\vec r')dV$$
where the integral is evaluated in one conductor, and
$$V(\vec r) = \int \dfrac{ρ(\vec r')}{|\vec r - \vec r'|}dV$$
where the integral is evaluated along the two conductors.

How can we prove from these that $Q$ and $V$ are proportional?

Answer (score 3):

Notice how in both $Q$ and $V$ the charge density is acting in the same way in the integrals.$^*$ Scaling $\rho$ by some constant will scale $Q$ and $V$ by that same constant, so that $Q/V$ will not change at all.

---

$^*$However, beware of blindly throwing equations around.

In $C=Q/V$, $Q$ is the amount of net charge on one conductor (so that one has $+Q$ charge and the other has $-Q$ charge), and the $V$ is the potential difference between the conductors.

On the other hand, the equation you give for $Q=\iiint\rho(\mathbf r')\,\text d\tau'$ is the total charge in the system (which we usually assume is $0$ for a overall neutral system), and $V=\iiint\rho(\mathbf r')/|\mathbf r-\mathbf r'|\,\text d\tau'$ is the potential at position $\mathbf r$ assuming that $V\to0$ as $\mathbf r\to\infty$ (this is not the same thing as the potential difference between the two conductors).

Of course you can tweak / qualify these equations so that they are valid for the capacitor, but since this was not specified I thought I should address it.

Answer (score 1):

Capacitance is determined by the physical characteristics of the conductors and space between them. For a parallel plate capacitor the capacitance is

$$C=\frac{εA}{d}$$

Where $ε$ = the permittivity of the medium (dielectric) between the capacitor plates, $A$=the plate area and $d$ = the distance between the plates. So as long as these physical parameters involving the conductors and space between them do not change, the capacitance is constant.

Then, for a fixed physical device (capacitor), $C$ in the equation

$$C=\frac{Q}{V}$$

is constant, meaning only charge and voltage vary, with the ratio of charge to voltage being constant.

It is important to realize $Q$ is the *net charge* on either plate, positive on one and negative on the other and equal in magnitude. That makes the net overall charge on the capacitor zero (overall electrically neutral). In this regard @BioPhysicist has already correctly addressed the integral equations for $Q$ and $V$.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of capacity states that its body is equipotential.  So C = Q / U , and you used the wrong formula for potential. U is the potential difference between the metal parts of the capacitor.